# Why doesn't Stack Exchange do more to prevent irrelevant answers?

Tags: discussion

Scenario:
ProgrammerX asks: "How to do THIS with THAT tool"
Answers are: "Why do it with THAT tool, just use SOMETHING_ELSE"

"Oh, really, thanks, I didn't know Java existed! I was writing this automation in Batch Script because I can obviously install 3'rd party software on the subject machine but I quite fancy the powerlessness"

Equally frustrating is to search for something, find the exact question already asked, see it has been answered, only to find out the accepted answer is:
"Why do it with C? Learn Java and use that"

Well, next time I see a "how to do this with PROGRAMMING_LANGUAGE" question I might as well answer:
"Why do you want to do this with VBA? Why do you even want to program? Learn medicine and be a doctor - it's more profitable!"

I think the above phenomenon makes for irrelevant answers (that get selected nonetheless, because OP changed his restrictions, something not all developers can do) and general waste of time.

If I ask how to do something with COBOL, it's because I need that particular tool, not because I am unaware of much newer programming languages. I think asking that more often frustrates the OP rather than bring anything useful in.

Comment: So.... it's not okay to tell someone "hey dude, coding this in that language is a bad idea, if you are not REALLY limited by which language you need to use, using this instead is WAY better"? If you find a question but you can't abide with changing your language, ask again, link into the probable duplicate, and say "the answers here use Java. I can't use Java, I NEED C, because XYZ reason"

Comment: Answers who only say things like *Why do it with THAT tool, just use SOMETHING_ELSE* would be shot down pretty quickly. Are you sure the users you mention are not expressing that opinion in *comments* instead?

Comment: If it's on your question, just mention in your question when you write it that you _have_ to use x tool/language because y reason. (For example: "I know there's newer technology I can use to solve `z`, but my company requires that all projects by done in "x" and I cannot use something different.) Then if you get "You shouldn't use X you should use 42!" that's a bad answer. If you see this on other questions and the OP accepted the suggestion as their answer, there's not a lot you can do about the OPs decision.

Comment: Absolutely.
I ask something about EZASOKET, get answer: "Just use CTG!"...
Yeah, I'll introduce a dedicated middleware and change the coupling of my programs, why didn't I think of that earlier?...

Comment: @Drax, could you provide a link to such an answer?

Comment: @DraxDomax but do you explain why you cannot move from EZASOKET? When you come to stack, you come for expertise. Sometimes the proper answer is "did you consider throwing what you have away and using someting else? it'll be WAY simpler". If it isn't possible for you, explain why. And if the "answer" is "just use CTG", then Frederic is on the right path... that's a comment, not an answer

Comment: SE's business is selling job advertisements, they are quite uninvolved with the Q+A at SO.  Downvoting bad answers is *your* job.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/246262

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger, that ship has sailed :) The current incarnation of that meme is *Use moment.js*.

Comment: The value of an answer is typically going to be up to the community in contrast to the question being asked. It's not going to be something the person raising the question has much *direct* control over with 1 vote. However, the person asking the question actually has a *tremendous amount of indirect control*. The clearer you make your question, the more obvious it becomes if someone isn't answering it effectively. For example, even if you omitted the information initially about why you are using a specific tool, you can edit your post immediately to include it at the very top of the question.

Comment: In general here on Meta, I feel like there's too much focus on the answers -- trying to prevent "bad" ones, trying to prevent even good answers to bad questions, etc. The questions are where it's at -- that's what we should be looking at most IMO. This site seems to care about posterity, but it locks in even the poorest questions once an answer is provided. Now you get all these people obsessing about shooting questions down as quickly as possible before they get a single answer -- but probably a more critical examination of what we really want would be more effective.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This isn't something that the autonomous site can regulate.  This is something that the community *has* to step in on and manage.

There are a lot of valid answers that come from, "No, you don't want to do it that way for [insert reasons here], use [this] approach.", and we don't want to diminish that at all.  Code changes, libraries become old and deprecated, or platforms disappear that are simply too costly to maintain and update.  If the site were to try to divine which of those answers followed the above pattern, and these answers were *genuinely* useful, then we'd be losing a lot of good information.

The other part to this here is that the community, as I mentioned above, can step in and act on this anyway.  If you don't think an answer is satisfactory, downvote it.  The OP may be frustrated, but patience (and a clear reason why it *must* be done in a specific way) are necessary.

Answer (score 10):

Stack Exchange does more than enough **to allow you to handle the situation**.

If it doesn't answer the question, downvote it. If it doesn't even attempt to answer the question, flag it as not an answer.

But if it answers the question, yet doesn't fit your particular constraints, make sure to state the constraints within which you're operating.

And as the OP, it's up to you whether or not you accept an answer. If it doesn't work for you, don't accept it.